# What type of questions do we need to ask on Meta?

Tags: support, meta

What type of questions do we need to ask on Meta and why on Meta only?

Only stack-related website question do we need to ask or can we ask any other website-related questions?

Comment: @Servy think we just found a bug with hammers, we should be able to close only based on original tags, isn't it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard If you edit the tags, you can't hammer it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307650/3541881

Comment: What do you mean by "stack-related"? Are you referring to one specific site in the Stack Exchange network, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Answer (score 0):

We have a [help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on every site which covers this. Press the help button on the top bar to navigate there.

But to answer your question, no you can't ask other website related questions here or on any per-site meta either. All meta questions need to be about the current Stack Overflow site or for this meta about all Stack Overflow sites.